# Pass a parameter without exposing ids

Tags: apex, visualforce, pagereference

Is that possible to pass an parameter without exposing in the URL?

```
public PageReference goToNextPage() {
    PageReference pageRef = Page.MyNextPage;
    pageRef.getParameters().put('AccId', accountId);
    return pageRef;
}
```

it shows in the url

> .../apex/newPage?AccId=00156000002zGVsAAM

But I would like that not to show in the URL, the above is just an example and I have couple of parameters that I'm passing but the requirement is not to expose to the end user, have anybody done similar or have an idea how to do that?

Comment: The key question is: *why* do you care?

Comment: customer care and its part of requirement.

Comment: Just because they say it matters doesn't mean you should listen to them. Get a concrete justification for why, otherwise it's frivolous nonsense.

Comment: also the part of that is the same concept so when you go to the salesforce and https://XXXX.salesforce.com/type_id_here it will let you redirect to the page based on the id... and restricting the end-user changing the ids

Comment: @NickKahn - if you are passing params via url, even if you do not show them the user could still change the url like they were there and by design your controller would handle them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do one of two things:

1. <strike>Set redirect to false. The URL in the browser ***should*** not be updated. Could cause issues depending on the circumstances and the page redirected to must be using the same controller)</strike>
2. Encode the parameters and decode them in the controller which may satisfy your requirements

But ask yourself first like Adrian said, why does it matter?

Comment: Another not so easy option would be to store parameters in browser cookies and reading those from the new page but again it is not worth the extra effort.

Comment: Third totally overkill option: encrypt the parameters and decode them in your Apex Code.

Comment: The first option will not work. SetRedirect to false will not work if the two pages are of different controllers. Even if they are of the same thing, it will not trigger the constructor firing again which means the parameter passed will not work.